# Remove Calendar Preview from Reading Pane in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there a way to remove the calendar preview from the reading pane in Outlook 2013?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the little arrow to collapse the calendar view:

[image]

Outlook will remember your choice for that setting in future invites.